# Convert a JObject to a strongly typed object

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I'm using `JsonConvert` to serialize and deserialize objects from classes like this:

```cs
public class DbBulkRequest
{
    public DbEntity[] Updates { get; set; }
}

public class DbEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Dto { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize `Dto`, I get an object of type `JObject`. At the time of deserialization, I want to create strongly typed objects based on `Dto`. I can create the objects; however, I don't know of a good way of populating their properties. The best I've found is this cheeseball approach:

```cs
MyEntity e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEntity>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto));
```

What would be a more efficient solution?

Comment: I don't think this is more efficient but at least more readable(I think) `MyEntity e = JObject.FromObject(dto).ToObject<MyEntity>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`TypeNameHandling`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)

```
private readonly JsonSerializerSettings defaultSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    };
```

Here's example

```
private readonly JsonSerializerSettings defaultSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    };

[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var entity = new DbEntity
        {
            Dto = new TestDto { Value = "dto" },
            Name = "Entity"
        };
    string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, defaultSettings);
    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbEntity>(serializedObjest, defaultSettings);
}

public class DbBulkRequest
{
    public DbEntity[] Updates { get; set; }
}

public class DbEntity
{
    public object Dto { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestDto
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```