# Trouble deserializing JSON with array into object

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, json.net

I am sending JSON from my Angular frontend (with HttpClient post) to my VB.NET backend but I cannot seem to deserialize it correctly.

JSON

```
{  
   "taxRate":0,
   "shipping":0,
   "items":
  [  
   {  
      "id":392184,
      "name":"",
      "price":0,
      "image":"",
      "quantity":1,
      "data":"sku1"
   },
   {  
      "id":338429,
      "name":"",
      "price":0,
      "image":"",
      "quantity":1,
      "data":"sku2"
   },
   {  
      "id":386646,
      "name":"",
      "price":0,
      "image":"",
      "quantity":1,
      "data":"sku3"
   }
  ]
}
```

My classes

```
Public Class CartDTO
  Public Property Shipping As Decimal
  Public Property TaxRate As Decimal
  Public Property Items() As CartItemDTO
End Class

Public Class CartItemDTO
  Public Property Id As Integer
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Image As String
  Public Property Price As Decimal
  Public Property Quantity As Integer
  Public Property Data As String
End Class
```

Controller function to catch this:

```
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Object)
'breakpoint
End Sub
```

If I put `value As String` then `value` is null.

If `value As CartDTO` then `value` is an empty CartDTO.

If `value As Object` then `value` is of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` which has the correct data, but I can't work out how to easily get it into my DTO...

Trying this:

```
Dim ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of CartDTO)(value)
```

...gives me System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'JObject' to type 'String' is not valid.'

What am I missing?

Edit - or how can I receive the json as a string?  Not sure why `value` is Nothing when I try that.

Comment: Looks duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363139/error-when-deserializing-json-to-object

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, with a combination of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363139/error-when-deserializing-json-to-object) 2 [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847052/convert-a-jobject-to-a-strongly-typed-object/20847796).

Change DTO to

```
Public Class CartDTO
  Public Property Shipping As Decimal
  Public Property TaxRate As Decimal
  Public Property Items As List(Of CartItemDTO)
End Class
```

And do this:

```
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Object)
  Dim o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)
  Dim ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of CartDTO)(o)
  'ob is now a nicely filled CartDTO as expected
End Sub
```

It seems like there should be a better way... but this works.

Comment: Declare your `value` parameter as `JObject`.  Then you can do `Dim ob = value.ToObject(Of CartDTO)(value)`